# Inject ngMaterial using webpack, angular fullstack generator

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, angular-fullstack

I want to build a web application and I have started building this by using the angular fullstack generator. This generator uses webpack and this is the first time I am using webpack.

I have been trying to add the `ngMaterial` dependency by installing it with:

`npm install angular-material --save`

I have added the dependency in the `config.entry.vendor` from the `webpack.make.js` file but when I tried to import the `ngMaterial` i received the following error:

`ERROR in ./client/app/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ngMaterial' in path\client\app
 @ ./client/app/app.js 21:18-39`

How can I inject a dependency with webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you pointed incorrect dependency name in webpack configuration: `ngMaterial` instead of `angular-material`.

`ngMaterial` is angularjs module name, you point it as a dependency in your angular app module, like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
```

But in `webpack` dependencies you have to point `node.js` module name, which is `angular-material` (it is located in `node_modules` folder after you install it via `npm install` command)

**EDIT:**

If needed in your `app.js` you also have to import that module via `import 'angular-material'` or `require('angular-material')`. But if you include this dependency in separate `vendor.js` file (via `webpack`), than you shouldn't ever include this module in your `app.js`, cause it will upload to the page in `vendor.js`. You'll include it 2 times in your project if you do so.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I solve the problem. Can you tell me where I can find more documentation about webpack so I can document myself on this subject? Thanks

Comment: Here are good youtube playlists of [webpack lessons](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCblk3IlXm_ZXkR5OYLuYWaQ/playlists) by Matthew Hsiung. Basics and some advanced config examples.